# Problems serializing a dictionary with TouchJson

Tags: iphone, json, ios, ipad, touchjson

i'm developing a small app for the ipad and i'm trying to serialize a dictionary to NSData to save in the disk. I'm using with framework TouchJson.
And example of my example structure:

```
{
line =     {
    78986928 =         (
        "NSPoint: {442, 266}",
        (...)
        "NSPoint: {370, 634}"
    );
};
```

}

The structure of my dictionary is: an dictionary with dictionaries inside. This dictionaries have a string (ID) and an NSMutableArray with an NSValue.

The line of code is that i'm using is:

`NSData *jsonData = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeObject:templates error:&error];`

The error that the variable error give me is:

```
2011-03-23 10:12:12.957 GestureFramework[286:207] Error Domain=TODO_DOMAIN Code=-1 "Could not serialize object '{
line =     {
    78986928 =         (
        "NSPoint: {442, 266}",
        (...)
        "NSPoint: {370, 634}"
    );
};
}'" UserInfo=0x4e27aa0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not serialize object '{
    line =     {
        78986928 =         (
            "NSPoint: {442, 266}",
            (...)
            "NSPoint: {370, 634}"
        );
    };
}'}
```

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TouchJSON supports serializing the following types:

- NSNull
- NSNumber
- NSString
- NSArray
- NSDictionary
- NSData

If you'd like to serialize another type you'll need to implement `-(NSData*)JSONDataRepresentation` (either on a subclass or category).

Here's an example that I used for `NSDate`:

```
@interface NSDate (JSONDataRepresentation)
- (NSData*)JSONDataRepresentation; 
@end
```

.

```
@implementation NSDate (JSONDataRepresentation)
- (NSData*)JSONDataRepresentation 
{
    return [@"\"didn't want to waste the space to do the real conversion\"" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
}
@end
```